# rails rspec, any way to handle multiple 'should' for the same example via a block?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

Suppose the model method foo() returns an array `[true, false, 'unable to create widget']`

Is there a way to write an rspec example that passes that array as a block that verifies [0] = true, [1] = false, and [2] matches a regex like /

Currently, I do it like:

```
result = p.foo
result[2].should match(/unable/i)
result[0].should == true
result[1].should == false
```

I can't quite get my head around how that might be doable with a block?

Comment: Can you be more specific about what you're trying to achieve by using a block? As written your code looks OK. (Some people would say that each example should only have one "should" in it; but not everyone.)

Comment: It might be just fine as is, just looked a little cumbersome having to identify the [0] [1] manually so I thought there might be some magic idiom that makes it cleaner looking.

Comment: If all the tests were ==, you could do something like `result.should == [:a, true, false]`. But once that match gets in there, I think you've done the best you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would be slightly over engineered but try to run this spec with `--format documentation`. You will see a very nice specdocs for this method ;)

```
describe '#some_method' do
  describe 'result' do
    let(:result) { subject.some_method }
    subject { result }

    it { should be_an_instance_of(Array) }

    describe 'first returned value' do
      subject { result.first }
      it { should be_false }
    end

    describe 'second returned value' do
      subject { result.second }
      it { should be_true }
    end

    describe 'third returned value' do
      subject { result.third }
      it { should == 'some value' }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that your `result` is an array and you have to iterate over to test it's various cases?

Then, you can do that by following, right:

```
result = p.foo
result.each_with_index do |value, index|
  case index
  when 0 then value.should == true
  when 1 then value.should == false
  when 2 then value.shoud match(/unable/i)
  end 
end
```